# найти элемент по тексту в теге span

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите, как найти элемент по тексту в теге span?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно найти по xPath `//span[contains(text(),'11A-7E2-V0005')]`

Comment: а можно ли как-то текст 11A-7E2-V0005 заменить переменной, потому-что генерируется уникальный, а потом чтоб подтягивать?

Comment: все можно. зависит где вы это хотите применить. например, на ЯВУ можно  так `"//span[contains(text(),'" + myLocalVar + "')]`"`